# Install Ubuntu on Windows machine

Tags: system-installation

I am a new Ubuntu user with years of experience using Macs. Today for the first time I got a Windows machine ( IBM T31, 1GB RAM, 1.6Ghz CPU, 20GB HDD ), and I wanted to install Ubuntu so I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 as well as 13.04. Ubuntu 12.04 did not recognize my wired network. Ubuntu 13.04 did recognize my network and installed properly. After the installation was finished, I rebooted and got nothing. How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean with 'nothing'? Black screen? Error? Just boots to Windows? ... Please edit your question to include. No offense :)

Comment: Actually, I feel like you should edit your question and provide us with some information on your wired adapter... is it an Add-on PCIexpress card, built-into the motherboard (as most are for a while now)?  What can you tell us about the ethernet adapter you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your network connection is what is not working and that your installation of Ubuntu is working. Your question is a little vague in this area.

If your network isn't working, check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide) out. It should help you to diagnose you problem.

Comment: It looks like he installed 13.04 and his network is working but he can not start Ubuntu for some reason.

Comment: It looked to me like he meant here: "After rebooting after installation: nothing." that the network connection didn't work.